# I think clearInterval problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came here like many beginners :D So without wasting a time I will explain my problems.

http://heavenpro.lt/ukv - website of demo. There a 2 users etc.

```
sekret - demo 
demo - demo
```

(for login) if you will see any error - would be happy to know to have a chance to solve it.
When users turned off (Išj. - button) demo user sees log: Waiting for student (Laukiama studento)

after sekret turn it on (Įjungt - button) everything seems okay, demo user sees active user, after clicking to next one - gives alert that was changed student and if you want to update information (to see new one) however.. after turning off (Išj. button) Works good in all browsers except IE.. Seems that clearInterval not works and after lot of sent queries and respons it pops out more than one Alert window.. 
Hope you understood that i mean.

```
var sid = "{$i->sid}";
var mid = "{$i->mid}";

var update_st = setInterval(function(){
    $.post(
        'ajax/check-student.php',
        { sid: sid, mid: mid },
        function(resp){
            if(resp == "next") {
                var cf = confirm('Buvo pakeistas studentas besiginantis darbą. Ar rodyti sekantį studentą?');
                clearInterval(update_st);

                if (cf) {
                    window.location = "?";
                } 
                else {
                alert('Kai norėsite perjungti kitą vartotoją, prašome perkrauti puslapį.');
                clearInterval(update_st);
            }
        } 
        else if (resp == "none") {
            alert("Gynimas baigtas. Ačiū už dalyvavimą vertinimo komisijoje.");
            clearInterval(update_st); // this place not works..
            window.location = "?";
        }
    });
}, 250);
```

Tested lot times.. seems sometimes works normaly.. Tested on IE 9..

Of maybe can anyone offer any others ideas to do same way? Without many queries per second sending to file...

Comment: would be nice to know what are you trying to do here. because your code seems a bit strange :)

Comment: Kadangi Tu lietuvis galiu paaiškint papraščiau lietuviškai :D Esmė: Darbų vertinima komisijoje. T.y sedi komisija, žmogus ginasi darbą o komisija vertina. Sekretorė perjunginėja studentą. Kol studento nėra, sistema tikrina ar dar neijungtas, ir jei ijungia studenta - ji ikrauna.. kad nebutu window.location.reload() kol įjungs.

Comment: o ar patikrinai kokį responsone tau grąžina? nes gal tas ifas tiesiog nesuveikia if(resp == "none")

Comment: Suveikia :) tik esme tame, kad man suveikia 20+ kart ir ismeta ta pati alert daug kart. Per daug net.. Bet suveike to komentadas. Anyway duosiu + ir Tau, kad nepatingėjai pažiūrėt.

Comment: suveikia per daug kartų nes setInterval funkcijai nurodei būti vykdomai kas 250 milisekundžių ;) aš sakyčiau užsidėk bent jau 5000 (5 sekundes) ir bus ok viskas ;)

Comment: negerai :/ Man reikia, kad RT (Real-time) sistema būtų.. T.y. kuo greičiau atnaujintų tuo geriau.. Pagal įdėja geriau būtų PostgreSQL, nes joje yra funkcija gražinanti atsakymą tik atlikus pakeitimams, o MySQL to neturi.. O kadangi čia mano baigiamasis darbas, o kolegija tik SQL suteikia :D kito pasirinkimo neturiu, kaip kuo mažesnį laiko tarpą dėt.. O host'ai irgi MySQL suteikia dažniausiai..

Comment: jei nori real time, tai reikia programinti jau socketus :) tiek AJAX užklausų belsdamas į serverį tik imituoji RT ir aišku smarkiai apkrauni patį servą. jei paleis 10-100 client, servas užsilenks :)

Comment: Jei prastas serveris taip, jei padorus.. čia tiek užklausų nėra taip ir daug.. o Socket'us.. su PHP galima daryt?

Comment: Tiesiog pasiskaityt gali http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setTimeout instead of setInterval, many reasons...
So you will call function that creates setTimeout! And this method will guarantee that your code will be executes iff query to server is done!

```
var a = function(){
    var timer = setTimeout(function(){
        // ok your ajax query success of error whatever
        a();
        console.log(2)
    }, 1000);
}

a();
```

You must put your query inside setTimeout, and call **a** function after query done or whatever!

So [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G3Mpa/)